New node cannot join, connection fail during the streaming
I have 3 node cassandra cluster (version 4.1.5). I am trying to join a new node. I've started the new node, the node is in a joining state and data are replicated to it. But after some time the streaming fail with the connection error.
There is a log from the new node (172.19.40.181):
INFO  [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-6b20291f] 2024-06-25 09:01:00,242 BigTableZeroCopyWriter.java:214 - Writing component FILTER to /var/lib/cassandra/data/contentserver/content-c690778f2c3e32dba8becd143349730a/me-11837-big-Filter.db length 0.492KiB
INFO  [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-6b20291f] 2024-06-25 09:01:00,242 BigTableZeroCopyWriter.java:224 - Block Writing component to /var/lib/cassandra/data/contentserver/content-c690778f2c3e32dba8becd143349730a/me-11837-big-Filter.db length 0.492KiB
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-7] 2024-06-25 09:01:05,225 OutboundConnection.java:1059 - 172.19.40.181/172.19.40.181:7000->/172.19.40.162:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-76765806 channel closed by provider
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
WARN  [OptionalTasks:1] 2024-06-25 09:01:05,526 CassandraRoleManager.java:359 - CassandraRoleManager skipped default role setup: some nodes were not ready
INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2024-06-25 09:01:05,526 CassandraRoleManager.java:395 - Setup task failed with error, rescheduling
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-7] 2024-06-25 09:01:05,896 OutboundConnection.java:1153 - 172.19.40.181/172.19.40.181:7000(/172.19.40.181:51424)->/172.19.40.162:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-bbda823d successfully connected, version = 12, framing = CRC, encryption = unencrypted
WARN  [OptionalTasks:1] 2024-06-25 09:01:15,527 CassandraRoleManager.java:359 - CassandraRoleManager skipped default role setup: some nodes were not ready
INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2024-06-25 09:01:15,527 CassandraRoleManager.java:395 - Setup task failed with error, rescheduling
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2024-06-25 09:01:18,897 Gossiper.java:575 - Convicting 172.19.40.162/172.19.40.162:7000 with status NORMAL - alive true
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2024-06-25 09:01:18,897 Gossiper.java:1382 - InetAddress 172.19.40.162/172.19.40.162:7000 is now DOWN
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2024-06-25 09:01:18,897 Gossiper.java:575 - Convicting 172.19.40.161/172.19.40.161:7000 with status NORMAL - alive true
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2024-06-25 09:01:18,898 Gossiper.java:1382 - InetAddress 172.19.40.161/172.19.40.161:7000 is now DOWN
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2024-06-25 09:01:19,898 Gossiper.java:575 - Convicting 172.19.40.163/172.19.40.163:7000 with status NORMAL - alive true
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2024-06-25 09:01:19,898 Gossiper.java:1382 - InetAddress 172.19.40.163/172.19.40.163:7000 is now DOWN
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-7] 2024-06-25 09:01:21,899 NoSpamLogger.java:105 - 172.19.40.181/172.19.40.181:7000->/172.19.40.162:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-[no-channel] failed to connect
io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /172.19.40.162:7000
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$2.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:576)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
WARN  [OptionalTasks:1] 2024-06-25 09:01:25,527 CassandraRoleManager.java:359 - CassandraRoleManager skipped default role setup: some nodes were not ready
INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2024-06-25 09:01:25,528 CassandraRoleManager.java:395 - Setup task failed with error, rescheduling


The log from the node 172.19.40.162:
DEBUG [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.181:7000-c1d71211] 2024-06-25 09:00:55,816 StreamDeserializingTask.java:74 - [Stream #19fcf270-32bd-11ef-89a7-8f46be4777f5 channel: c1d71211] Received Received (c690778f-2c3e-32db-a8be-cd143349730a, #268)
DEBUG [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.181:7000-c1d71211] 2024-06-25 09:00:55,816 StreamTransferTask.java:93 - received sequenceNumber 268, remaining files [257, 258, 260, 261, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 269, 270, 271, 272, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284>
WARN  [Streaming-EventLoop-4-21] 2024-06-25 09:01:01,046 DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1152 - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-1] 2024-06-25 09:01:01,264 OutboundConnection.java:1059 - 172.19.40.162/172.19.40.162:7000->172.19.40.181/172.19.40.181:7000-SMALL_MESSAGES-ad6e55e6 channel closed by provider
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-1] 2024-06-25 09:01:01,501 NoSpamLogger.java:105 - 172.19.40.162/172.19.40.162:7000->172.19.40.181/172.19.40.181:7000-SMALL_MESSAGES-[no-channel] failed to connect
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: 172.19.40.181/172.19.40.181:7000
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
        at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:124)
        at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:673)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:530)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-3] 2024-06-25 09:01:01,749 OutboundConnection.java:1059 - 172.19.40.162/172.19.40.162:7000->172.19.40.181/172.19.40.181:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-c57ee1ce channel closed by provider
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
ERROR [Messaging-EventLoop-3-11] 2024-06-25 09:01:01,895 InboundMessageHandler.java:298 - /172.19.40.181:7000->172.19.40.162/172.19.40.162:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-e481b08c unexpected exception caught while processing inbound messages; terminating connection
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2024-06-25 09:01:01,900 MigrationCoordinator.java:268 - Pulling unreceived schema versions...
ERROR [NettyStreaming-Outbound-/172.19.40.181.7000:7] 2024-06-25 09:01:02,085 StreamSession.java:725 - [Stream #19fcf270-32bd-11ef-89a7-8f46be4777f5] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 172.19.40.181:7000 through 172.19.40.181:32702
org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncChannelOutputPlus$FlushException: The channel this output stream was writing to has been closed
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncChannelOutputPlus.propagateFailedFlush(AsyncChannelOutputPlus.java:200)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncChannelOutputPlus.waitUntilFlushed(AsyncChannelOutputPlus.java:158)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncChannelOutputPlus.waitForSpace(AsyncChannelOutputPlus.java:140)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncChannelOutputPlus.beginFlush(AsyncChannelOutputPlus.java:97)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncStreamingOutputPlus.writeFileToChannelZeroCopyThrottled(AsyncStreamingOutputPlus.java:242)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncStreamingOutputPlus.writeFileToChannelZeroCopy(AsyncStreamingOutputPlus.java:211)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncStreamingOutputPlus.writeFileToChannel(AsyncStreamingOutputPlus.java:165)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CassandraEntireSSTableStreamWriter.write(CassandraEntireSSTableStreamWriter.java:93)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CassandraOutgoingFile.write(CassandraOutgoingFile.java:167)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingStreamMessage.serialize(OutgoingStreamMessage.java:87)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingStreamMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingStreamMessage.java:45)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingStreamMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingStreamMessage.java:34)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.serialize(StreamMessage.java:39)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.async.StreamingMultiplexedChannel$FileStreamTask.run(StreamingMultiplexedChannel.java:319)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask$1.call(FutureTask.java:96)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask.call(FutureTask.java:61)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:71)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Suppressed: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
                at org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncStreamingOutputPlus.doFlush(AsyncStreamingOutputPlus.java:82)
                at org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncChannelOutputPlus.flush(AsyncChannelOutputPlus.java:229)
                at org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncChannelOutputPlus.close(AsyncChannelOutputPlus.java:248)
                at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.async.NettyStreamingChannel$1.close(NettyStreamingChannel.java:141)
                at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.async.StreamingMultiplexedChannel$FileStreamTask.run(StreamingMultiplexedChannel.java:320)
                ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: sendfile(..) failed: Broken pipe
DEBUG [NettyStreaming-Outbound-/172.19.40.181.7000:7] 2024-06-25 09:01:02,086 StreamSession.java:561 - [Stream #19fcf270-32bd-11ef-89a7-8f46be4777f5] Changing session state from STREAMING to FAILED
DEBUG [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2024-06-25 09:01:02,086 StreamSession.java:561 - [Stream #19fcf270-32bd-11ef-89a7-8f46be4777f5] Changing session state from FAILED to FAILED

I tryied nodetool bootstrap resume but it failed again after 10-50 minutes.
I tryied to set:
streaming_keep_alive_period_in_secs: 60
internode_streaming_tcp_user_timeout: 600000ms

but the streaming failed again. The first ERRORs in log:
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-c9f53dea] 2024-06-26 09:02:03,241 StreamSession.java:683 - [Stream #f3ecbce0-3385-11ef-8f4a-e1e57dddacb9] Socket closed before session completion, peer 172.19.40.163:7000 is probably down.
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-69225b73] 2024-06-26 09:02:03,245 CassandraEntireSSTableStreamReader.java:146 - [Stream f3ecbce0-3385-11ef-8f4a-e1e57dddacb9] Error while reading sstable from stream for table = contentserver.content
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-a74f4df4] 2024-06-26 09:02:03,245 CassandraEntireSSTableStreamReader.java:146 - [Stream f3ecbce0-3385-11ef-8f4a-e1e57dddacb9] Error while reading sstable from stream for table = contentserver.content
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-0a510f22] 2024-06-26 09:02:03,245 CassandraEntireSSTableStreamReader.java:146 - [Stream f3ecbce0-3385-11ef-8f4a-e1e57dddacb9] Error while reading sstable from stream for table = contentserver.content
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-07d67e0b] 2024-06-26 09:02:03,245 CassandraEntireSSTableStreamReader.java:146 - [Stream f3ecbce0-3385-11ef-8f4a-e1e57dddacb9] Error while reading sstable from stream for table = contentserver.content
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-5ea07b1e] 2024-06-26 09:02:03,245 CassandraEntireSSTableStreamReader.java:146 - [Stream f3ecbce0-3385-11ef-8f4a-e1e57dddacb9] Error while reading sstable from stream for table = contentserver.content
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-e632e731] 2024-06-26 09:02:03,245 CassandraEntireSSTableStreamReader.java:146 - [Stream f3ecbce0-3385-11ef-8f4a-e1e57dddacb9] Error while reading sstable from stream for table = contentserver.content
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-d4b871b3] 2024-06-26 09:02:03,245 CassandraEntireSSTableStreamReader.java:146 - [Stream f3ecbce0-3385-11ef-8f4a-e1e57dddacb9] Error while reading sstable from stream for table = contentserver.content

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack 
UN  172.19.40.161  1.1 TiB    256     66.0%             
UN  172.19.40.163  1.12 TiB   256     67.1%             
UJ  172.19.40.181  41.28 GiB  256     ?                 
UN  172.19.40.162  1.16 TiB   256     66.9%             

EDIT again,again
ERROR logs from .163
ERROR [Messaging-EventLoop-3-17] 2024-07-01 10:01:01,239 InboundMessageHandler.java:298 - /172.19.40.181:7000->172.19.40.163/172.19.40.163:7000-SMALL_MESSAGES-94fa126a unexpected exception caught while processing inbound messages; terminating connection
ERROR [Messaging-EventLoop-3-13] 2024-07-01 10:01:01,811 InboundMessageHandler.java:298 - /172.19.40.181:7000->172.19.40.163/172.19.40.163:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-c420dd44 unexpected exception caught while processing inbound messages; terminating connection
ERROR [NettyStreaming-Outbound-/172.19.40.181.7000:22] 2024-07-01 10:01:02,160 StreamSession.java:725 - [Stream #24c5ece0-377f-11ef-8904-e587a1989bf2] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 172.19.40.181:7000 through 172.19.40.181:23490
... Previous error repeated several times
RROR [NettyStreaming-Outbound-/172.19.40.181.7000:10] 2024-07-01 10:01:03,161 StreamSession.java:725 - [Stream #24c5ece0-377f-11ef-8904-e587a1989bf2] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 172.19.40.181:7000 through 172.19.40.181:23490
ERROR [Messaging-EventLoop-3-20] 2024-07-01 10:01:07,813 InboundMessageHandler.java:298 - /172.19.40.181:7000->172.19.40.163/172.19.40.163:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-5db0209f unexpected exception caught while processing inbound messages; terminating connection
ERROR [MutationStage-1] 2024-07-01 10:01:25,584 Keyspace.java:650 - Unknown exception caught while attempting to update MaterializedView! contentserver.content
ERROR [MutationStage-1] 2024-07-01 10:01:25,584 JVMStabilityInspector.java:68 - Exception in thread Thread[MutationStage-1,5,SharedPool]
ERROR [MutationStage-2] 2024-07-01 10:01:25,721 Keyspace.java:650 - Unknown exception caught while attempting to update MaterializedView! contentserver.content


ERROR logs from .163
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-0369a6a0] 2024-07-01 10:02:23,081 StreamSession.java:683 - [Stream #24c5ece0-377f-11ef-8904-e587a1989bf2] Socket closed before session completion, peer 172.19.40.163:7000 is probably down.
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-739a078c] 2024-07-01 10:02:23,086 CassandraEntireSSTableStreamReader.java:146 - [Stream 24c5ece0-377f-11ef-8904-e587a1989bf2] Error while reading sstable from stream for table = contentserver.content
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-3d1128b9] 2024-07-01 10:02:23,087 CassandraEntireSSTableStreamReader.java:146 - [Stream 24c5ece0-377f-11ef-8904-e587a1989bf2] Error while reading sstable from stream for table = contentserver.content
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-df1b030f] 2024-07-01 10:02:23,087 CassandraEntireSSTableStreamReader.java:146 - [Stream 24c5ece0-377f-11ef-8904-e587a1989bf2] Error while reading sstable from stream for table = contentserver.content
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-00c68108] 2024-07-01 10:02:23,087 CassandraEntireSSTableStreamReader.java:146 - [Stream 24c5ece0-377f-11ef-8904-e587a1989bf2] Error while reading sstable from stream for table = contentserver.content
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-ffdaf624] 2024-07-01 10:02:23,087 CassandraEntireSSTableStreamReader.java:146 - [Stream 24c5ece0-377f-11ef-8904-e587a1989bf2] Error while reading sstable from stream for table = contentserver.content

The same ERROR message
ERROR [Messaging-EventLoop-3-17] 2024-07-01 10:01:01,239 InboundMessageHandler.java:298 - /172.19.40.181:7000->172.19.40.163/172.19.40.163:7000-SMALL_MESSAGES-94fa126a unexpected exception caught while processing inbound messages; terminating connection
was in the log of other nodes .161 and .162 in the same time.
It seems to me that the connection between .181 and .163 was unexpectedly closed without no obvious reason.

Finally I found out that the problem was on the network level.
There was some collision IP in the network. It causes disrupting connection every hour.

Unfortunately, the log messages you posted are not relevant to the failed bootstrap or streaming errors so it's not possible to determine what is causing the node to fail.
You will need to go back to the logs and look at specific ERROR messages that indicate joining failures then update your post.
As a general recommendation, streams can fail when (1) the nodes have a lot of data (greater than 1TB), (2) have a lot of indexes defined so need to be built during bootstrap, or (3) both.
In any case, the bootstrapping node could connections with other nodes that appear to be idle. If there is a firewall between nodes, it could be inadvertently terminating the sockets because it thinks they are no longer required.
On the Cassandra side, consider tuning the following parameters in conf/cassandra.yaml:
internode_streaming_tcp_user_timeout: 300000ms
streaming_keep_alive_period: 300s

Note that these parameters are only relevant if the issue turns out to be due to streaming timeouts. Cheers!
EDIT - Here's my response after the post was edited.
This log message:
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-c9f53dea] 2024-06-26 09:02:03,241 StreamSession.java:683 - [Stream #f3ecbce0-3385-11ef-8f4a-e1e57dddacb9] Socket closed before session completion, peer 172.19.40.163:7000 is probably down.

indicates that the remote node 172.19.40.163 closed the socket before the streaming session completed.
And the messages that look like this line are reporting that there was an error reading the files for table contentserver.content:
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/172.19.40.163:7000-69225b73] 2024-06-26 09:02:03,245 CassandraEntireSSTableStreamReader.java:146 - [Stream f3ecbce0-3385-11ef-8f4a-e1e57dddacb9] Error while reading sstable from stream for table = contentserver.content

You need to review the logs on node 172.19.40.163 to figure out why it was reporting errors reading that table.

Yes, every node has more than 1TB of data. I've updated the post.

Stream ID f3ecbce0-3385-11ef-8f4a-e1e57dddacb9 has a timestamp of June 26 06:33 GMT. What timezone are the logs in, Moscow MSK?

I am in the timezone CEST. GMT+2h

Cassandra is running from 2024-06-26 08:32:21 (6:32 GMT). Streaming failed in 9:02 after 30 minutes.

I've updated my answer. Cheers!

I've added the log. I noticed that every attempt fail one minute after a full hour. O9:01, 10:01 and so on. Can it mean anything?

You need to look at the logs on node .163 specifically looking for messages relating to (1) failure to read table contentserver.content, and (2) errors relating to the failed stream ID. Those will give you clues as to why the bootstrap is failing. INFO messages are not useful since they don't tell you why the stream failed. Cheers!

I have read the logs thoroughly but no clue why the bootstrap is failing. I've updated the post with the only two type of ERROR messages found in the log of .163

The error on node .163 at 13:01:02 says that the FlushException was thrown because the output stream with .181 was closed. What kind of errors are reported on node .181 at 13:01:02 (or a few seconds before)?

The challenging bit here is that you are looking at errors at different times when you need to focus at just one failure at a very specific time. When I first started helping you, I was only looking at the bootstrap failure at 2024-06-26 09:02:03 but now you're posting errors from 2024-06-27 and I have no way of correlating today's errors from what I was investigating yesterday. Does that make sense?

If you look at errors from a different timeframe, there are no guarantees that you are investigating the same root cause so you have to limit your investigation on a specific bootstrap failure or we'll be going around in circles. I hope that makes sense.

Yes, it makes sense. I tried it several times and always add last logs, sorry for that. But the error messages was the same. The original question is now pretty long, I will edit it again with the log with the same timeframe.

Is the correct approach to edit the original question again and again? Should I only add new logs?
